# Is it possible to perform bind mount as a non-root user in an unshared namespace while preserving your UID and groups?

Tags: linux, mount, root

I want to run a process as my (non-root) user with an unshared bind mount. I can do this.

```
$ unshare --mount --map-root-user mount --bind foo bar
```

While this works, I am faking root in this context. I want to run the subsequent process as myself. I can preserve my identity with `--map-current-user` but obviously mount then fails.

```
$ unshare --mount --map-current-user mount --bind foo bar
mount: bar: must be superuser to use mount.
```

I then had the idea to add a `user` entry for this mount to `/etc/fstab`. It works outside the namespace but still stubbornly refuses to work inside it. Of all my attempts, this failure is the one I found most surprising.

```
$ unshare --mount --map-current-user mount bar
mount: bar: must be superuser to use mount.
```

Okay, it's a little unpleasant but how about mounting via sudo? Nope.

```
$ unshare --mount --map-current-user sudo mount --bind foo bar
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 65534, should be 0
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

Fine, the performance may suck but surely the FUSE-based bindfs will work? Nope.

```
$ unshare --mount --map-current-user bindfs -o nonempty foo bar
fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted
```

It's awkward but what if I fake root first and then switch user again? There are various ways to do this but they were all nope.

```
$ unshare --mount --map-root-user runuser -u ${USER} someprocess
runuser: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted
```

I then discovered `nsenter`, which allows you to run a command in the context of a namespace from outside of it. However I use it, it won't let me enter the mount namespace.

```
nsenter --mount --target 1234 mount bar
nsenter: reassociate to namespace 'ns/mnt' failed: Operation not permitted
```

I thought namespaces were supposed to reduce the need for sudo. Is there really no way to do this?

Since originally posting this, I recalled the existence of [proot](https://proot-me.github.io/), which actually can do this. I used to be a big fan but I ran into various issues and upstream development slowed. I see that there was a new alpha release recently, which is encouraging, but it still hasn't fixed seccomp and I think I'll need that as the process I want to run is Steam. It also has some fairly high CPU overhead, which I want to avoid. I feel like what I'm asking for shouldn't incur much overhead. proot at least proves that the kernel does allow this and it may just be the userspace tools that are lacking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question as I've now discovered the existence of [Bubblewrap](https://github.com/containers/bubblewrap/). It's used in Steam, amongst other things. It is similar to proot but seemingly without the downsides. You can use it like this:

```
bwrap --bind / / --dev-bind /dev /dev --bind "${PWD}"/foo "${PWD}"/bar -- "${SHELL}"
```

[Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) may be another possibility but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [faketree](https://github.com/enfabrica/enkit/tree/master/faketree). It's used in CI/CD pipelines and [EDA Environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_design_automation), to create file system views for specific build steps without root while preserving UID/GID, sane signal handling, propagating error status, and guaranteeing cleanup.
It can remap **files** and **directories** without having to deal with `/dev`, `/` or similar.

For example:

```
$ echo "127.0.0.1 builder" > ./fake_etc_hosts
$ mkdir -p opt_build
$ touch opt_build/testfile

$ faketree --mount fake_etc_hosts:/etc/hosts \
           --mount opt_build:/opt/build -- "$SHELL"
$ ls
testfile
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 builder
```

It has flags to override the hostname (`--hostname`), change the working directory (`--chdir`), and tune the behavior with flags.

From the project documentation:

> - **Does NOT require root**, any user can run it as long as pid and user namespaces
>   are enabled on the system (and they are by default on most modern linux distros,
>   you can use the included test to verify).
> - **Runs commands with the same UID/GID of the user**, does NOT create a shell
>   that appears to run as root (can be overridden by flags)
> - **Does NOT require `LD_PRELOAD`, ptrace, or similar tricks**. It works with static
>   binaries as well as with binaries that require a modified `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or
>   `LD_PRELOAD`, or have protections to prevent tracing.
> - **Affects only the commands run within faketree**, which means you can run multiple
>   instances of faketree in parallel by the same user on the same system and with different parameters.
> - **Propagates environment variables and privileges correctly**, allowing even graphical
>   tools to run correctly within faketree.
> - **Does NOT rely on FUSE**, disk performance and performance are unaffected.
> - **Can override individual files**, including `/proc` and `/sys` files.
> - **Tries to handle signals correctly**, so integration in a CI/CD pipeline should be
>   straightforward. Sending SIGTERM to faketree will propagate to the children, and
>   faketree will correctly wait for all children and descendants to terminate before
>   exiting. A `kill -9` of faketree will guarantee all descendants being killed as well.
> - If the wrapped command calls realpath or checks the filesystem,
>   the command will see just a normal file system with mounts.

There's also a [blog post here](https://blog.enfabrica.net/different-file-system-views-for-different-tools-a425f13bb7f0) that describes its utilization.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/767296/139357) has some working examples that use unshare (not as root) and nsenter (as root inside the container) to cause bind mounts, and invokes them in a synchronized way to do that you want. Real root access is not required

Sadly it requires util-linux 2.39.1 which probably means ubuntu 23.04 or later.

Note that the unshare invocation has what were previously mutually exclusive options.

I'm still trying to get it to work for earlier ubuntu, e.g. 22.04 (the most recent LTS). I'll stop trying once 24.04 is out.

But as brwap is available in more places than util-linux > 2.39.1 right now, I think that your bwrap solution is better.

Comment: Please include enough of a working answer instead of a link-only reference

Comment: @random I would normally agree with you, but as mentioned, I'm still improving it and I don't want to leave a stale answer here, but more significantly, it's a stack exchange answer that I'm pointing to, it's not going anywhere, it's likely to be available for as long as this answer is available. There's maybe six pointers to that answer spread over the sites, I'm not keeping them all up to date.